# Data format in Ext JS forms and Django models is equivalent, but not works

Tags: django, extjs, date-formatting

When I POST my form, I receive the following exception:

`act_date: ["Date has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY-MM-DD."]`

And the same validation error for other `DateField`s.

I changed the default date format in extjs (`Ext.util.Format.defaultDateFormat= 'Y-m-d'`) which did not work.

So next I define date format in Django setting:

```
'DATE_FORMATS': [("%Y-%m-%d"),],
```

This also hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

When you said *`I changed the default date format in extjs (Ext.util.Format.defaultDateFormat= 'Y-m-d') which did not work.`* it's the date format don't work or again you'r server validation ?

Cause actually if i do this :

```
var d = new Date();
Ext.Date.format(d, 'Y-m-d');
```

That give me : "2019-03-05" and it's seem to be correct.

Have you check inside of you'r POST request the format of the sending date ?
You maybe have a unexpected date format before sending you'r request.

Comment: " it's the date format don't work or again you'r server validation ?" ,  again server validation. Date looks correct, like  "2019-03-05" , but Chrome throws validation message..

Comment: how I can define POST params for different dataformat for different fields ? Not all fields in the form are datefields